# How to remove special characters from text using php and regex

Tags: php, regex, replace

I have a string

```
$k="My name is Alice[1]";
```

What i want is to remove "[1]" from my string Using minimum steps,So that sentence will look like

```
$k="My name is Alice";
```

So antything that come inside [] should be removed.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: nothing :-( not able to get it

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/tW2cRE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$text = preg_replace('/\[[0-9]+\]/','',$text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [preg_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for this.

```
echo preg_replace('/\[[0-9]+\]/','',$str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$k="My name is Alice[1]";
$k = preg_replace('/\[[0-9]+\]/','',$k);
```